# Listview not working... (Objects are not valid as React Child)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am currently building an app in which I am trying to implement the React Native Listview functionality. I am however at a standstill...

The code below yields simply the error: Objects are not valid as React Child (found: objects with keyes {name, img, .... } )

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    loaded: false;

     return { 
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.friendFeed),
   };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
       <ListView 
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
          renderRow={this.CardViewer}
          style={styles.card} /> 
      )
  },

  CardViewer(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    console.log(rowData.friend);
    return (

        <CardView
          name={rowData.friend}
          fullname='xyz'
          distance='xyz'
          title={rowData.post}
          message={rowData.post} 
          score='xyz'
          stars='xyz'
          starcolors={colors.General.black}
          vouched="Example" />
      )
  }
})
```

But if I instead try to write the Cardviewer as: `... <CardView name={rowData.friend.name} ...` it will return the error that undefined is not an object. But I dont know how to further set some loading state on each of those...

I create the data that I use in the following manner:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      componentSelected: 'One',
      tokenSupreme: 'Loading big token...',
      userName: "Loading...",
      friendFeed: 'Loading...',
    };
    loaded: false;
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {

    Method.loginUser(AccessToken)
    .then((res) => this.setState({
      userName: JSON.parse(res).user.name,
      tokenSupreme: JSON.parse(res).token,
    }))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .done();
    loaded: true;
    exports.tokenSupreme = this.state.tokenSupreme;
  },

  changeComponent: function(component) {
    Method.getFriendFeed(this.state.tokenSupreme)
    .then((res) => this.setState({
      friendFeed: JSON.parse(res).friendPosts,
    }))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .done();

    this.setState({
      componentSelected: component
    })
  },
  renderComponent: function(component) {
      if(component === 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne friendFeed={this.state.friendFeed} />
      } else if(component === 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo />
      }
  },
```

Where have I gone wrong? My guess is because that I dont predefine som state before loading which throws the object not defined, but then again, the Listview does not seem to have that as an option, or then again, I have (most likely) probably misintepreted it. So, please help! :)

EDIT: 
Trying to manipulate the execution order via the component-lifecycles I made it so that loaded = true when the frienFeed is executed, and by then I have my render as an if function so that it renders "loading" untill otherwise. But it never seems to re-evaluate the if statement. Because I can see in my log how loaded = true, but it does not react. Code as the following in the ComponentOne:

```
  render: function() {
    if (this.state.loaded != true) { 
      return this.renderLoadingView(); 
    } else if(this.state.loaded === true) {
      console.log('trying...');
      console.log(this.state.props.friendFeed);
    return (
       <ListView 
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          style={styles.card} /> 
      )
    }
  },
```

Comment: CardViewer is supposed to be a function. Was that a typo in your sample code ?

Comment: I tried to replicate as much as possible from this example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#final-source-code in which they wrote their rendermovie in a similair sense.

Comment: ok. That link is using es6(es2015) javascript syntax. You are using es5 syntax . In your case, it should be a function. renderRow should be a function. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

Comment: If it helps, you can refer here https://github.com/agenthunt/react-native-scratchpad/blob/master/SimpleListViewExample/SimpleListView.js for a simple listview example

Comment: It think the issue lies within the component lifecycles and the fact that before it has properly fetched the data, there will exist nothing which is called rowData.friend.name for example.